# How to show that $\mathcal{O}_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be a ring and $\mathcal{O}$ be a sheaf of rings on $\operatorname{Spec} A$. The elements of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is of the form $<U, s>$, where $U$ is an open neighborhood of $P$ and $s$ is an element of $\mathcal{O}(U)$. How to show that the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{\mathfrak{p}}$ of $\mathcal{O}$ is a ring? What is the multiplication and addition in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathfrak{p}}$? If we have two elements $<U, s>$ and $<V, t>$, what are $<U, s> + <V, t>$ and $<U, s> \cdot <V, t>$? Thank you very much.

Comment: $\langle U,s\rangle \dot+ \langle V, t\rangle = \langle U \cap V, s|_{U \cap V} \dot+ t|_{U \cap V}\rangle$.

Comment: More generally, if $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is any ringed space, and $x \in X$, then $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} := \mathrm{colim}_{x \in U \subseteq X \text{ open}} \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is a ring, because it is a directed colimit of rings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on martini's answer, the actual definition of $\mathcal{O}_\frak{p}$ is the collection of such pairs $\langle U, s \rangle$, with an added equivalence relation that $\langle U, s \rangle = \langle V, t \rangle$ if $\mbox{res}_{W}(s) = \mbox{res}_{W}(t)$ for some open set $W$ containing $\frak{p}$.

Now, suppose we wish to add or multiply two elements $\langle U,s \rangle$ and $\langle V, t\rangle$. It might not make sense to do so if you only consider $s$ and $t$ directly, since they live in different rings. But, because of our equivalence relation, $\langle U, s \rangle = \langle U \cap V, \mbox{res}_{U \cap V}(s)\rangle$. Similarly, $\langle V,t\rangle = \langle U \cap V, \mbox{res}_{U \cap V}(t)\rangle$. In both instances, we are setting $W = U \cap V$.

Now that we have represented our initial elements by two elements that actually live in the same ring, we can add or multiply them inside that ring, and the end product is the equivalence class of the resulting element.